# Program crashing ubuntu

Tags: nvidia, crash

I have a fairly graphics intense QT based proprietary program that keeps crashing at me when it runs out of memory.

When that happens it often takes down the entire system. Usually I can restart and the program will work again. However, this time it would refuse to start properly. Instead I see a transparent splash and then it blocks a CPU at 100% until the system freezes. I tried reinstalling the program and deleting all .* files.I previously managed to fix this by reinstalling the Nvidia driver. This times nothing seems to help.

Is there a way to find out what as specific program is doing on my system? Something like a traceback. As it is proprietary I don't get any output from the terminal.

And: No using a different free software is not an option.

Comment: Seems like a great support question for that proprietary vendor.

Comment: Most (all) programs will crash system when system runs out of memory. Add more memory (for performance) or more swap (for handling memory shortage, but with bad performance.

Comment: There are trace funktions, such as strace, that lets you see what your program makes of system calls.

Comment: Thanks. Strace did the job. You should post it as an answer. I will accept it.